# Gradle "Could not find method compile() for arguments" for Guava

Tags: eclipse, gradle, guava, buildship

Iv'e looked at the other "Could not find method compile() for arguments" questions here but found nothing to help me.

I'm using the Buildship plugin for eclipse to import a Gradle project. This is `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '20.0'
}
```

as described in https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UseGuavaInYourBuild. I use the wizard to import the project and get the following error (full stack trace here):

```
 Loading Gradle project preview failed due to an error in the referenced Gradle build. Could not fetch model of type 'GradleBuild' using Gradle distribution
 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.1-bin.zip'.

 Build file 'C:\Path\To\Project\ProjectName\build.gradle'
 line: 6 A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ProjectName'.
 Could not find method compile() for arguments
 [{group=com.google.guava, name=guava, version=20.0}] on object of type
 org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
 org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not fetch model of type
 'GradleBuild' using Gradle distribution
 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.1-bin.zip'.    at
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
    at
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
    at
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)     at
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:51)
    at
 com.gradleware.tooling.toolingclient.internal.DefaultToolingClient.executeAndWait(DefaultToolingClient.java:106)
    at
 com.gradleware.tooling.toolingclient.internal.DefaultModelRequest.executeAndWait(DefaultModelRequest.java:79)
    at
 com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository$1.get(BaseModelRepository.java:95)
    at
 com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.executeAndWait(BaseModelRepository.java:163)
    at
 com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.access$000(BaseModelRepository.java:41)
    at
 com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository$2.call(BaseModelRepository.java:121)
    at
 com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4724)
    at
 com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3522)
    at
 com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2315)
    at
 com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2278)
    at
 com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2193)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3932)     at
 com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4721)
    at
 com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.getFromCache(BaseModelRepository.java:138)
    at
com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.executeRequest(BaseModelRepository.java:117)
    at
 com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.BaseModelRepository.executeRequest(BaseModelRepository.java:88)
    at
 com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultSingleBuildModelRepository.fetchGradleBuildStructure(DefaultSingleBuildModelRepository.java:132)
    at
 org.eclipse.buildship.core.projectimport.ProjectPreviewJob.fetchGradleBuildStructure(ProjectPreviewJob.java:94)
    at
 org.eclipse.buildship.core.projectimport.ProjectPreviewJob.runToolingApiJobInWorkspace(ProjectPreviewJob.java:83)
    at
 org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiWorkspaceJob$1.run(ToolingApiWorkspaceJob.java:79)
    at
 org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiInvoker.invoke(ToolingApiInvoker.java:63)
    at
 org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiWorkspaceJob.runInWorkspace(ToolingApiWorkspaceJob.java:76)
    at
 org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55) Caused
 by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file
 'C:\Users\Nir\git\Sanctorum\GameClientLogic\build.gradle' line: 6 A
 problem occurred evaluating root project 'GameClientLogic'.    at
 org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
    at
 org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    at
 org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
    at
 org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:114)
    at
 org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at
org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
    at
 org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at
 org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:48)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:79)
    at
 org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:59)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:44)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at
 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:293)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
 Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred
 evaluating root project 'GameClientLogic'.     at
 org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:92)
    at
 org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:176)
    at
 org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
    at
 org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:181)
    at
 org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
    at
 org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:25)
    at
 org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at
 org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:573)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:125)
    at
 org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
    at
 org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
    at
 org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)    at
 org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
    at
 org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:148)
    at
 org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:33)
    at
 org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
    ... 42 more Caused by:
 org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException:
 Could not find method compile() for arguments
 [{group=com.google.guava, name=guava, version=19.0}] on object of type
 org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
    at
 org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.methodMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:182)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:89)
    at
 build_7qq3tniyxfzuiosj6471fjclb$_run_closure2.doCall(C:\Users\Nir\git\Sanctorum\GameClientLogic\build.gradle:6)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:70)
    at
 org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:160)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
    at
 org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.dependencies(DefaultProject.java:940)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:382)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:170)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:96)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.metaobject.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:30)
    at
 org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:163)
    at
 org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:83)
    at
 build_7qq3tniyxfzuiosj6471fjclb.run(C:\Users\Nir\git\Sanctorum\GameClientLogic\build.gradle:5)
    at
 org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
```

---

```
... 60 more
```

I don't understand what's the problem. I just copy-pasted the lines and this is a simple Java project. Currently I am using Eclipse to add the Guava jar to the Java build path and use it this way. But because this project will add another project dependency and itself be a dependency I rather let Gradle handle the transitive dependencies as described in its user guide.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't defined in your `buildscript`? The only dependency type allowed there is `classpath`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't apply either `groovy` or `java` plugin which provides `compile` config.

Add the following in the beginning of your `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```